# GridView: Get datakey of the row on button click

Tags: asp.net, gridview, gridviewrow

How can I get a value of the DataKeyName of a GridView Row when I have a button inside a row that have an OnClick event.  In my OnClick event of my button I want to get a the DataKeyName of the row where the button resides.

Is this possible?

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" run="server">
     <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 1">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   ... bunch of html codes
                   <asp:Button ID="myButton" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Text="Click Me" onclick="btnClick_Click" />
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In my codebehind

```
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // How can I get the DataKeyName value of the Row that the Button was clicked?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I'm working with a GridView, I usually do not use the `OnClick` event for buttons. Instead, I use the `OnRowCommand` event on the GridView, and bind data to the `CommandArgument` property of the button. You can retrieve the command argument from the `GridViewCommandEventArgs` parameter of the event handler.

You can use the `CommandName` parameter to bind an arbitrary string to distinguish between any different *kinds* of buttons you have. Note that some command names are already used for other events, such as "Edit", "Update", "Cancel", "Select" and "Delete".

**Update:**

Here is an example, assuming the data key is called "ID":

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="myGridView_RowCommand">
     <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 1">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   ... bunch of html codes
                   <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me" CommandName="ClickMe" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
protected void myGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var datakey = e.CommandArgument;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sweet!  Also i can use the `oncommand` event of the button in the row here without putting an `OnRowCommand` on the GridView.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the key to the CommandArgument property of the Button, and consume `(sender as Button).CommandArgument` property in the code

Comment: Close, except a regular `EventArgs` does not have a `CommandArgument` property. It is necessary to subscribe to a different event to get the property.